# Tomcat WebdavServlet to serve external directory

Tags: tomcat, webdav

Is there any way to make Tomcat [`WebdavServlet`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/servlets/WebdavServlet.html) to serve external directory rather than webapp context resources only? I learn that `WebdavServlet` extend [`DefaultServlet`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/servlets/DefaultServlet.html). And I try to extend `WebdavServlet` and, override `resources` `ProxyDirContext` but it didn't work this way. It return `null` and can't go out of a webapp context. I have this structure.

- Link: `http://localhost:8080/my-web-context`
- Deploy: `/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.56/webapps/my-web-context`
- WebDAV resources: `/data`

If I simply configure `WebdavServlet`, I can browse and access through `http://localhost:8080/my-web-context/webdav` of `my-web-context` web app resource only.

Or, perhaps, can I configure adding external resource (i.e. `/data`) into `WebdavServlet/DefaultServlet`, in addition to my webapp context resource? If so, this could solve my use case too. But symbolic link is not preferred. I know this kind of configuration can be easily done in Apache httpd webdav module but I want it on Tomcat for easy java webapp integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I got it working. The null issue is because `resources.getEnvironment()` return a blank environment object that is initialized at `DefaultServlet`. And `ProxyDirContext` constructor has `contextName = env.get(CONTEXT); int i = contextName.indexOf('#');` that will throw null. Anyway, here is the working code.

---

First, it extends Tomcat `WebdavServlet` and override `resources` inside servlet `init()` if external `repoPath` is configured.

```
public class MyWebdavServlet extends WebdavServlet {

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();

        String repoPath = getServletConfig().getInitParameter("repoPath");

        if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(repoPath)) {
            return;
        }

        FileDirContext fileDirContext = new FileDirContext();
        fileDirContext.setDocBase(repoPath);

        //Hashtable<String, String> env = resources.getEnvironment(); won't work, throw null when we construct ProxyDirContext!

        //setup environment object manually
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<>();
        env.put(ProxyDirContext.HOST, resources.getHostName());
        env.put(ProxyDirContext.CONTEXT, resources.getContextPath());

        resources = new ProxyDirContext(env, fileDirContext);
    }

    //do more override...

}
```

---

And the servlet mapping in `web.xml` will be:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>webdav</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sankholin.webdav.MyWebdavServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>listings</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>readonly</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>repoPath</param-name>
        <param-value>/data</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>webdav</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webdav/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```